# How to Mark Files to .ERROR Once The File Processsing is Failed and Exception Happened

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I want to mark the `.csv` file as `.ERROR` once the file processing is failed in the Apache Camel.

Some exception has occurred in the processing logic of the Apache Camel, so need to mark that file as `.ERROR` (un-processable file)

I am giving `?noop=true&exclude=.*.ERROR&moveFailed=/tmp/test` in the configuration parameter.

```
String operation="?noop=true&exclude=.*.ERROR&moveFailed=/tmp/test1";
```

First of all, the file with exception is not getting moved.

Second, I am not getting as how to change the extension from `.csv` to `.ERROR` using Apache Camel once the file processing throws exception.

Any suggestion on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify this in moveFailed where you can move and rename, see the file language docs at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/file-language.adoc

```
moveFailed=/tmp/test1/${file:name}.ERROR
```

Comment: Yeah done like this ${file:onlyname.noext}.ERROR.
Thanks.

Can you tell me how to configure camel context to read only 1 file, tried many approaches but none is woking. Any advice will be very helpful